# My Desktop application not able to call the API to fetch token using apache Oauth Client

Tags: java, swing, oauth-2.0

It is an swing desktop application we have functionality to login.
In one of our client machine with window 7 we are not able to connect to the our auth service due to the following error :-

```
org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthSystemException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:71)
    at database.TvilightIO.getAccessToken(TvilightIO.java:53)
    at gui.MainScreen.showLoginScreen(MainScreen.java:218)
    at gui.MainScreen.<init>(MainScreen.java:48)
    at tester.Tester.<init>(Tester.java:112)
    at tester.Tester.main(Tester.java:312)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:
    242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(
    AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.jav
    a:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java
    :1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractD
    elegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.
     java:1362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.j
    ava:1337)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConne
    ctionImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:85)
    ... 8 more
```

As we have migrated the our application from Java 8 to java 11.

Comment: check your windows firewall, antivirus software.

Comment: but the old version with java8 is able to request our server, would it be related ti upgrading to java11 or something.

Comment: This is an server problem . Ur server works with clients of java 8 and cannot handle connections from java 11 users so it needs to be upgraded. Java is platform independent but still version dependent

Comment: If it is version problem then how it is running in all other machines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to firewall restriction applied by the network.
So once host was permitted through firewall, then it started working perfectly.